# What is the best way of architecture selection for deep neural networks

Tags: keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am training a deep network with Adam optimizer. For single hidden layer, I used to do statistical calculations (coefficient of correlation, MSE etc.) and plot them to select optimum number of hidden nodes. Is there any methodology to select optimum structure for deeper networks? (apart from trial and error.)

Answer (score 0):

Hyperparameter optimization is still an open problem and it is done mostly by trial and error, especially in case of neural networks.

Except for some general guidelines such as monitoring the performance (under/over-fitting), there is not much you can do (if you have a better solution, you can easily market it these days, just search google for paid hyperparameter optimization services and you will see it growing by day).

That being said, you don't need to perform the search manually (manually changing the structure of a neural network/train/repeat). ML libraries (such as Keras and many others) offer some kind hyperparameter grid search where you can set up values/ranges for hyperparameters you want to optimize and let the grid search find the optimal solution (optimal withing the range of values defined by you so it may not be optimal at all if incorrectly configured).

In case of Keras, you can use [keras tuner](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner).

Of course, running the tuner can be pretty expensive (depending on the complexity of the network).